# Kubernetes Job backoff limit wait time

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a Kubernetes Job with a `backofflimit` value set to `4`. So I would want to know that if there's a Pod in the Job that is failed, I would want to wait for n minutes or n seconds before the second pod is created. Is there a way how I can do it?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-test
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: bitnami/git:latest
        command: ["/bin/bash",  "-c", "gits clone ls -b master"]
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
  backoffLimit: 4
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [liveness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request)

See this example `Yaml` and `#you can change as per your need.`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-test
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pi
          image: bitnami/git:latest
          args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
          livenessProbe: # Check if healthy
            exec:
              command:
                - cat
                - /tmp/healthy
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
          command: ["/bin/bash",  "-c", "gits clone ls -b master"]
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
  backoffLimit: 4
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 120
```

**Note for `initialDelaySeconds`**: If you don’t set the initial delay, the prober will start probing the container as soon as it starts, which usually leads to the probe failing, because the app isn’t ready to start receiving requests. If the number of failures exceeds the failure threshold, the con- tainer is restarted before it’s even able to start responding to requests properly.

**Note for Pod backoff failure policy:** Failed Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job controller with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s ...) capped at six minutes. [Ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-backoff-failure-policy):

Comment: This is a brilliant idea. Thanks, Gupta !! But I want to achieve this only for failed containers. For example when I am initially running the job I don't want it to wait for n time, I would basically want it to wait only when there's a new pod created by the backoff limit.

Comment: @Pavan - Like you said _I would basically want it to wait only when there's a new pod created by the backoff limit_  #=> Failed Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job controller with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s ...) capped at six minutes.

Comment: So, Is there no way to change that 10s, the 20s ... to the specific time I want?

Comment: For that, you need to customize and I'm not that expert to do, it because I did not get a chance to modify it. Well, As per the source code https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/batch/v1/defaults.go#L42 it has been hardcoded.